Does not stretch in height ViewPager2
The image at the top of the screen does not stretch in height, and the bottom is empty. How can I stretch it to fit the screen and maintain proportions? 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MediaViewerActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        />

    <!-- Баннер рекламы, накладывающийся поверх ViewPager -->
    <com.yandex.mobile.ads.banner.BannerAdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_container_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

